# Simple POST request to PHP from Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am new to developing Windows Phone applications using C# and I am trying to send some data through POST to a PHP file from my Windows Phone 7 application on click of a button. I wish to receive the reply from the PHP script and print it out to a Text Block. I have tried some code samples from MSDN, but they throw some errors which I am not able to understand.

This was the sample from MSDN that I tried : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktfa4fek%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

I ran into many errors by trying the above example. Can anyone help me with the C# code to send POST data to PHP and receive response from it? Also, to get the response, is it enough to Echo the data from PHP or do I need to do something else like returning the value?

Comment: For the future and in order to be sure that your PHP script works well, don't hesitate to use _Advenced Rest Client_ chrome extension ;)

Comment: The following are the errors I get: 
1. 'System.Text.Encoding' does not contain a definition for 'ASCII' 
2. 'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'UploadData' and no extension method 'UploadData' ...
3. 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' could be found.

Comment: Check out http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http. With this class its pretty easy to send POST, GET and FILES data to PHP scripts...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to use an example from the full .NET Framework.  Windows Phone 7 does not support the full .NET framework.  Your app actually has to target the Silverlight Framework, and if you look at the `WebClient` class in Silverlight, there is no `UploadData()` method.

You have to use one of the [appropriate methods in `WebClient` for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_methods%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Without knowing more of your code and what you are trying to upload, it is hard to say which one, but you have several overloads of `UploadStringASync()` or `OpenWriteASync()` to choose from.

Likewise the other classes you are trying to use do not have the methods in the Silverlight framework